# NHibernate - "Session is closed! Object name: 'ISession'

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate on a custom membership provider in a MVC3 application.  Whenever I try to login though, I get the exception:

> Session is closed! 
>   Object name: 'ISession'

The code in the membership provider looks like this:

```
ContractRepository repository;
public string UserDescription { get; set; }

public CustomSqlMembershipProvider() {
    this.repository = new ContractRepository(ProviderPortal.Persistance.NHibernateSessionStorage.RetrieveSession());
}

public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password) {
    var user = repository.GetContractForUser(username);
    if (user == null)
        return false;
    else {
        UserDescription = user.Description;
        return true; //TODO: come back and add user validation.
    }
}
```

And here is the retrieve session methods:

```
public static ISession RetrieveSession() {
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    if (!context.Items.Contains(CURRENT_SESSION_KEY)) OpenCurrent();
    var session = context.Items[CURRENT_SESSION_KEY] as ISession;
    return session;
}

private static void OpenCurrent() {
    ISession session = NHibernateConfiguration.CreateAndOpenSession();
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    context.Items[CURRENT_SESSION_KEY] = session;
}
```

This is where the exception is happening:

```
public Contract GetContractForUser(string UserName) {
    return (Contract)session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Contract))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Login", int.Parse(UserName))).UniqueResult();
}
```

Somewhere between the CustomSqlMembershipProvider constructor being called, and the ValidateUser method being called, the session is being closed.  Any ideas?  My other Controllers are injected with an open session via DI, but this one is giving me the hardest time.

Comment: Not to thread jack but this kind of nightmare with the session management with NHibernate is what made me stop actively developing with it.

Comment: @Chris: you should use Spring for managing transactions.

Comment: Session management is ridiculously easy to manage with NH...

Comment: @Phill try to do something complicated with it, like implement the long conversation pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get this one consistently or on and off?

We were getting this using Spring.net for our DI and using OpenSessionInView

We had to add the following http module to change the storage options for the current thread.

```
public class SpringThreadStorageModule : IHttpModule
{
    static SpringThreadStorageModule()
    {
        LogicalThreadContext.SetStorage(new HybridContextStorage());
    }



    #region IHttpModule Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        // we just need the staic init block.
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: it seems to be on and off.  Yesterday it was working fine, but this morning it's back.  Not sure what to make of it....

Comment: I think what is happening is, that the session is being stored by one thread and then the request is finished on another thread where the session isnt there.  So by setting the above it is told to stay on one thread.

Comment: We had exactly this and were debating weather to use the WebSupportModule (as this sets this value) but as we were not sure whether we needed the other stuff it does, we just implemented our own httpmodule (above) that sets it.

Comment: I wonder if it would be better to put the repository back in the controller constructor and let my normal DI (Castle Windsor) do it's thing.  This works on all my other controllers.  By doing this though, I would need to set some type of flag in the membership provider to let me know if the user successfully logged in or not.

Comment: Can i ask, why do you pass in your session in to the constructor?  Why dont you just call sessionfactory.getcurrentsession inside your dao(repository)

Comment: I had the GetContractForUser method in a base repository class, in some of the other repositories I filter the data by the contract that the user logged in with.  I just changed it so I store my contract inside the session at login, this way I don't need to go back to the database and validate each time.  This seems to be working.